# Are there any pitfalls when passing function pointers between compilation units?

Tags: c, callback, function-pointers

I ask because i am using a PIC microcontroller to asynchronously operate hardware and implementing function pointers as a callback mechanism would be of benefit.

An example would be whereby an i2C library accepts read and write 'jobs' and sequentially executes each 'job' as the hardware resource becomes available (and as the user ticks the i2C software state machine). Depending on the implementers use of the i2C library, they may wish to manipulate the data prior to returning it, (bitmasking, setting flags etc) this is where i'm thinking of adding an i2C callback mechanism.

The user would pass a job, which includes a callback function pointing to the calling compilation unit. Is this allowed? and are there any cases that i need to be careful of if it is allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing pointers between compilation units is done all the time. For example, `free()` in the standard library is certainly compiled separately and yet takes a pointer as its argument.

Within many projects, including the Linux kernel, callbacks between compilation units are used often.

The main key is to use common header files for defining shared variables, making function definitions, and such. If you define a function using a `long` pointer, but call it using a declaration that specifies a `char` pointer, you're entering Undefined Behavior territory.

Also watch out for compiler flags that may change variables sizes, default packing, and such.